# Get-ADUser -filter parsing

Tags: powershell, parsing, filter, wildcard

I am running a script which takes a person's first and last name from an SAP extract, and reads AD to get their UPN. For most people, this works; however there are a bunch of users whose first name is an issue. For instance "Philip Davies" (names changed to protect the innocent) in SAP is "Phil Davies" in AD. So: I have used the following command and it works:

Code:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=CBC Users,DC=cbc,DC=int" -Filter {GivenName -eq "Phil" -and Surname -eq "Davies"}
```

I then realised I can check for the first three characters which will NORMALLY be the same in the contracted name... so I did this which also works:

Code:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=CBC Users,DC=cbc,DC=int" -Filter {GivenName -like "Phi*" -and Surname -eq "Davies"}
```

Next step: variables; so I try this and it works:

Code:

```
$fna="Phil"
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=CBC Users,DC=cbc,DC=int" -Filter {GivenName -eq $fna -and Surname -eq "Davies"}
```

But if I try this:

Code:

```
$fna="Philip"
$fna=$fna.Substring(0,3)
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=CBC Users,DC=cbc,DC=int" -Filter {GivenName -like $fna* -and Surname -eq "Davies"}
```

I get no result. It doesn't matter if I use brackets, double-quotes, single-quotes, anything. As soon as I try to parse a variable AND use a wildcard, it either produces an error message or no result.

Can anyone please help me with this either by using the *"-ldapfilter"* method or telling me how to parse AND wildcard?

Thanks

Comment: Try `$fna="Phi*"` outside the filter scriptblock

Comment: Sadly it parses the asterisk as part of the string if I do that, not as a wildcard. Sorry I forgot to add this to my post.

Comment: Remember to still use `-like $fna` inside the filter block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the wildcard with a variable since you wish to check it with a name which is a string. So what you can do is directly wrap the string with the wildcard and store the final thing in a variable like:

```
$fna="Philip"
$fna="$($fna.Substring(0,3))*"

Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=CBC Users,DC=cbc,DC=int" -Filter {GivenName -like $fna -and Surname -eq "Davies"}
```

or you can use the LDAP Filter directly like :

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=CBC Users,DC=cbc,DC=int" -LDAPFilter "(&(GivenName=$fna)(Sn=Davies))"
```

Hope it helps.